# Finding files with a name pattern

Tags: python, glob

I need to find whether a file with specific pattern name is available in a current directory or not. I used the following code for this purpose.

```
H1 = []
for record_name in my_list:
    file_name = 'RSN' + '_' + record_name[0:5] + '*' + record_name[-8:]
    H1 += glob.glob(record_name)
```

It should be noted that I used the above method because in some cases there are some differences between the available record_name and the real name of the file available in the current directory. For example, the true name for one of my file is "RSN20148_BB40204628_KRPHHZ", while I have "20148_40204628_KRPHHZ" in my_list. Please note that the second one does not have "RSN" and "BB" terms.

The above procedure works, but the problem is that it takes a lot of time. Is there any suggestion to reduce the time? 
Please note that I can not use `os.listdir()` to get the name of all files because the order of files in my_list is important for me.

Comment: How many files are in that directory?

What is the exact pattern that needs to be matched?

What is your `my_list`? And how big is it?

Without this information it's nearly impossible to figure out where your issue is. Are you sure that you don't just have so many files that it is bound to take a long time?

Also, how big/small your files are? Do you by any chance use Windows and have Windows defender on?

There could be a lot of things causing a slowdown, implying that it's something in your code causing it, which I think is unlikely, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implement an algorithm of yours where if record names are unique, you could create a dictionary ([orderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if Python < 3.6 else by default, dicts are ordered) with all the record names set to `False`.

Then use threading with `os.path.exists(path)` which sets that key to `True` or `False` depending upon if that record exists. Dictionary being `O(1)` with threading ***might*** give you a performance boost.

**A last note** - This is *all theoretical* and you would have to implement/optimise yourself to see if it gives you a performance boost at all *or* adds unnecessary overhead.

Cheers!